# Not able to get an entire string from oracle DB through perl script

Tags: oracle, perl

In my perl script I'm fetching records from oracle `DB.column:SQL_STATUS_INFO` with data type LONG.

```
$sql_statement = "select SQL_STATEMENT";
$sql_statement .= " from SQL_STATUS_INFO";

my $sql_return = SQL_Exec($sql_statement);
my $DbRtn_DB = SQL_Fetch();

foreach my $fromdb (@{$DbRtn_DB}) {
    printf "SQL_STATEMENT  :@{$fromdb}[0]\n";
}
```

`SQL_Exec`,`SQL_Fetch` are from perl module for executing the statements and fetching the results.

In the table `SQL_STATUS_INFO`, I have below data in column `SQL_STATEMENT`.

```
CREATE TABLE "ECLIPSFILE_4G_DUMMY_TRNX" (ENBID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),MCC NUMBER(38),MNC NUMBER,MNCLENGTH NUMBER,CELL_IDNUMBER(38),EARFCNDL NUMBER,PHYSICALID)
```

While fetching it through above script, I was not able to get the entire statement into `$DbRtn_DB`.

The output I am getting when I ran above script is:

```
CREATE TABLEECLIPSFILE_4G_DUMMY_TRNX (ENBID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),MCC NUMBER(38),MNC
```

So, I am not able to get the entire statement.

But I am able to insert the big text into db. I tried the above SQL statement in SQL_DEVELOPER and there it is giving me the entire string as output but not through the perl script.

How can I get that entire string into my perl variable.

Comment: Please add appropriate information. Your SQL query is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same errors when using `DBI` directly ?
In any cases, without seeing the code of `SQL_Exec` and `SQL_Fetch` it is hard to debug your problem.
The result you quote is specifically 80 characters long, which may not be a coincidence.